# Why can I use INSERT without any START TRANSACTION nor COMMIT/ROLLBACK with autocommit = 0 in mysql?

Tags: mysql, dml, autocommit

So I am trying to understand more about the autocommit statement in MySQL and I am having some trouble understanding why, after I use `SET autocommit = 0;` and try to run an `INSERT` without any `START TRANSACTION` and no `COMMIT/ROLLBACK` at the end it still inserts it into the table?

For what I understood, if the autocommit is equal to 1, it will commit automatically therefore it would make sense, but I set my autocommit to zero, therefore if I dont use any `START TRANSACTION` with `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` block surronding the insert it shouldnt work right?

I know there are some DML that commit automatically and i know that DDL statements do it as well, but in this case `INSERT` seems not to be any of the DML statements that does that.

The code goes as follow:

```
SET autocommit = 0;
SELECT @@autocommit; --It returns 0

-- No START TRANCATION
INSERT INTO example(first_name, last_name) VALUES ('TEST', 'TSET');
-- No COMMIT nor ROLLBACK
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see these rows in current session - but you'll not see them from another session.

Look:

[image]

Compare timestamps...

Comment: Thank you! You are 100% right. I choose you answer as the correct one! Thanks again!